# MikTeX does not see parent directory when running from within 10th version of WinEdt

Tags: paths, winedt, miktex2.9

I just installed trial version of `WinEdt 10.3`. With earlier versions of `WinEdt` I used relative path in `LaTeX` commands such as

```
\bibliography{../GDMT}
```

They allowed to read data from  `GDTMT.bib` file located in parent directory.

Similarly

```
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{}{../Graph/}{Graph/}{Graph/seminar/}}
```

allowed to read graphics files from `Graph` folder located in the parent directory. Such relative addressing still works with `WinEdt 9` but fails with WinEdt 10 on my laptop.

I have `MikTeX` and `Windows 10 Professional`.

Perhaps, `WinEdt 10` calls for `MikTeX` executables somehow differently from `WinEdt 9`? However, I did not noted any differences in their internal setting in the `Option` menu.

Comment: Did you try on a command line?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Yes, both xelatex and bibtex work from command line.

Comment: How is xelatex/bibtex setup in the options menu?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I added screenshot from WinEdt10 to my question. The same settings in WinEdt9.

Comment: There is not screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer given by Aleksander Simonic, the creator of WinEdt:

You are probably also using TeXAux folder to redirect output files. Correct? If so, start `Options Menu -> Execution Modes`.
For compilers that you are using (such as PDFLaTeX, bibtex, etc...) add a switch:

--include-directory="%P"

These switches are no longer used in the default settings because they do not act consistently between different TeX engines and accessories. That is the only difference. Note also that TeXAux folder may not always work with all packages or accessories (but 
that was the case in version 9 as well). The problem is that some accessories or packages implicitly assume that working directory is the location of the main file (which is not the case when you use TeXAux folder). Help in the execution modes explains some imitations of TeXAux folder…

Best regards,

alex